# How to change the margin size in one sided document, when using reledpar?

Tags: margins, geometry, reledpar

I am trying to use `reledpar` to typeset two texts with parallel alignment.
There are somewhere side-notes in the text. They should be rendered at the right side of the page.

Everything works perfect when I use two-side documents.

But when I switch to the one-side (and that's exactly what I need),
there is one problem:

The side note size becomes very small, and the text in the side-note is rendered with several line breaks:

[image]

How can I change the side-note size in this setup?

I tried to to do it with `geometry` but without any success:

```
  \documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

  \usepackage{reledmac}
  \usepackage{reledpar}

  \usepackage[
    top=0.2cm, bottom=0.2cm, right=2.5cm, left=1cm,
    heightrounded, marginparwidth=2cm, marginparsep=0.2cm
  ]{geometry}
```

`marginparwidth` seems to be ignored in this setup.

If I increase both `right` and `marginparwidth` it looks like this:

[image]

Here is a complete example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian,french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\usepackage[top=0.2cm, bottom=0.2cm, right=5cm, left=1cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=0.2cm]{geometry}

\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=TeX, SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
Le premier n’était autre que \textit{Mikhaïl Alexandrovitch Berlioz}\ledinnernote{\scriptsize \foreignlanguage{russian}{ Михаил Александрович Берлиоз }},
rédacteur en chef d’une épaisse revue littéraire et président de
l’une des plus importantes associations d’écrivains de Moscou
que l’on appelait en abrégé le Massolit.
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering

\foreignlanguage{russian}{

\pstart
Первый был не кто иной, как Михаил Александрович Берлиоз, председатель
правления одной из крупнейших московских литературных ассоциаций, сокращенно
именуемой МАССОЛИТ, и редактор толстого художественного журнала.
\pend

}
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch: Vielen Dank! Eine Antwort wäre aber noch besser :)

Comment: Don't show only code snippets, show a small but complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It's a good idea! It will certainly help to solve my problem. I've added a complete example

Comment: set the geometry before loading the reledmac package, or look up in its documentation how to change the width.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That's exactly that what I was looking for! I've changed the order of the packages and the problem was solved. Could you please move your answer to the answers section, so that I could accept it?